# Setting up Node.JS express HTTPS server fails with self signed key command

Tags: node.js, express, https, openssl

I'm generating a key / cert pair with the following OpenSSL command -

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

I then try to create a HTTPS node.js app like such -

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync( path.join(__dirname, '../keys/key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( path.join(__dirname, '../keys/cert.pem')), 
}, app);

httpsServer.listen(443);
```

However when I try to do a GET via https://localhost I get -

```
_tls_common.js:149
      c.context.setKey(key, passphrase);
                ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:149:17)
    at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1323:27)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:1181:8)
    // .....
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib',
    'error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error',
    'error:23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error'
  ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
}
```

Looking around the web I found [this tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) with the following commands -

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

Which when trying with the HTTPS node.js server on HTTPS localhost - things worked perfectly.

So my question is, what's the difference between the two set of OpenSSL commands I tried?
Ultimately - what I'm looking for is why the first command failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out that relying on [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) would handle all that for me.